# How to implement a custom allocator?

Tags: rust

I am looking for a way to implement something like a memory pool in Rust.

I want to allocate a set of related small objects in chunks, and delete the set of objects at once. The objects won't be freed separately. There are several benefits to this approach:

- It reduces fragmentation.
- It saves memory.

Is there any way to create a allocator like this in Rust?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It sounds like you want the [typed arena crate](https://crates.io/crates/typed-arena), which is stable and can be used in Rust 1.0.

```
extern crate typed_arena;

#[derive(Debug)]
struct Foo {
    a: u8,
    b: u8,
}

fn main() {
    let allocator = typed_arena::Arena::new();
    let f = allocator.alloc(Foo { a: 42, b: 101 });
    println!("{:?}", f)
}
```

This does have limitations - all the objects must be the same. In my usage, I have a very small set of types that I wish to have, so I have just created a set of `Arena`s, one for each type.

If that isn't suitable, you can look to [`arena::Arena`](http://doc.rust-lang.org/arena/struct.Arena.html), which is unstable and slower than a typed arena.

The basic premise of both allocators is simple - you allow the arena to consume an item and it moves the bits around to its own memory allocation.

Another meaning for the word "allocator" is what is used when you box a value. It is planned that Rust will gain support for "placement new" at some point, and the `box` syntax is reserved for that.

In unstable versions of Rust, you can do something like `box Foo(42)`, and a (hypothetical) enhancement to that would allow you to say something like `box my_arena Foo(42)`, which would use the specified allocator. This capability is a few versions away from existing it seems.

Comment: Thank you, this is exactly the same I want. Regarding the `box value` syntax, I think the syntax was in some older versions of Rust. Why was it removed and added again?

Comment: @unnamed_addr it wasn't removed or added again ^_^. It was marked *unstable*, which means it cannot be used in a stable version of Rust (like 1.0 or 1.1.beta), but can be used in unstable versions (1.2.dev). It was marked unstable purely because the developers have yet to hammer out all the details about how placement new should work, and supporting it in 1.0 means they would have to support it for the entire lifetime of Rust 1.x.

Comment: Sorry I didn't notice it. In the hypothetical enhancement you wrote, isn't that `box my_allocator Foo(42)`.

Comment: @unnamed_addr it depends? In my example, I'm assuming that there's some local variable called `my_arena` that can be used as an allocator, and in this case is an Arena-like allocator.

Comment: But doesn't `Box<>` free the memory when the variable goes out of scope? The objects allocated in the so-called "arena" can't be freed individually. So the `my_allocator` thing should implement a `free`-like method. Thus the hypothetical enhancement is something similar to how we pass custom allocators to STL containers. The word "arena" seems to be used only for allocators that don't allow objects to be destroyed individually, while the word "allocator" is more generic.

Comment: @unnamed_addr I think this discussion is part of the reason the `box` syntax is unstable ^_^. For example, should the `box` keyword always return a `Box` type? You may be interested in the [box syntax RFC](https://github.com/rust-lang/rfcs/blob/0806be4f282144cfcd55b1d20284b43f87cbe1c6/text/0809-box-and-in-for-stdlib.md) and the [feature gating box RFC](https://github.com/rust-lang/rfcs/blob/0806be4f282144cfcd55b1d20284b43f87cbe1c6/text/0469-feature-gate-box-patterns.md).

Comment: Sorry, I've mistaken again.

Comment: @unnamed_addr no worries - you aren't *mistaken*, it's just that this part of the language isn't completely fleshed out yet. Neither of us is right or wrong, because there isn't a "right" yet!

Answer (score 2):

Funny thing is, the allocator you want is already available in [arena](http://doc.rust-lang.org/nightly/arena/index.html) crate. It is unstable, so you have to use nightlies to use this crate. You can look at its [sources](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/blob/master/src/libarena/lib.rs) if you want to know how it is implemented.

Answer (score 2):

You may want to look at [`arena::TypedArena`](http://doc.rust-lang.org/nightly/arena/struct.TypedArena.html) in the standard library (*Note*: this is not stable and, as a result, is only available in nightly builds).

If this doesn't fit your needs, you can always examine the source code (you can click the `[src]` link in the top right of the documentation) to see how it's done.

Comment: The internal version isn't stable, but the external one on crates.io, which is the one you should be using, is.